# Oracle display all sql query run against DB by application

Tags: sql, oracle, text, trace

I have an old appliation/executable that loads data to Oracle DB that we are reverse engineering. We'd like to see all the sql generated by the application without stepping through source code. The source code has many different versions and may not match the executable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of sister site question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166607/how-to-capture-all-users-query-on-oracle-database

Answer (score 0):

```
select  v$sql.last_load_time, v$sql.sql_text 
from v$sql 
order by v$sql.last_load_time desc
```

First, you will need help from DBA to:

- grant permission to select from table v$sql.
- ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = true SCOPE=MEMORY; when done 
  ALTER SYSTEM SET sql_trace = false SCOPE=MEMORY;
- select sid, serial#, machine from sys.v_$session ;  find the sid and serial# for your machine and input to the next command
- execute sys.dbms_system.set_sql_trace_in_session(sid, serial#, true);
- flush the cache by executing following commands:

  `alter system flush buffer_cache;`

  `alter system flush shared_pool;`

Comment: You often do this ? Ask a question and answer right away ? I see in your previous few questions similar behavior...

Comment: @CaiusJard well I see he is not marking answers as correct ... :) I do not know if that is possible :)

Comment: Please give it a little time, I believe others will benefit. There was one upvote from my previous post, although downvoted by someone opposing my style.